# Proof of interference fringes take the same shape as the shape of the film?

Tags: optics, waves, interference, geometric-optics

(First of all I should mention time talking about interference between two reflecting rays thinking e.g. Newton's rings.)

Studying wave optics I have found that at the fringes take the same shape as the film placed between the light source and the screen.

So is there a satisfactory proof for which we can conclude that the the fringes have the the same shape as the film? What does it contradict in other configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newton's rings don't exactly have the same shape as the film, but they can be interpreted as contour lines of a topographic map of the thickness of the film.  The interpretation is complicated by such things as the tilt of the film relative to the incident light, the wavelength of the light, and the refractive index of the film.  This [article](https://www.ucd.ie/t4cms/2labman_newtons8.pdf) gives a good explanation of Newton's rings.